# Stop particles from rolling with camera (unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, particles

I have a particle effect. The particles face the camera with this setting

```
renderer-> render alignment -> face
```

or

```
renderer-> render alignment -> view
```

It's great that it faces the camera. But when I introduce a roll in my camera. For example for a VR game or a Space sim. The particles roll with the camera. Which looks horrible.

Is there a way that I can prevent this roll?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what you mean by roll?  Also did you try changing the billboard alignment settings?

Comment: Here is a youtube link how it looks.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z7RPGF8POCQ

Comment: And here is a link to a photo of my renderer settings
https://imgur.com/a/s6AxYEj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to point out that 2018.3 and on has an option in the render settings to "allow roll". Disabling this will solve the issue you have here.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this isn't currently possible in unity's particle system. It's a known problem especially for virtual reality. I coded my own particle system to go around this problem.